# Java what data structure use for List with more different data types?

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to pass more items with following data types:

```
OneListItem = (Integer, String, Intent);
```

So:

```
OneListItem.add(1,"Hello", IntentToPass);
OneListItem.add(2,"Hello", IntentToPass);
OneListItem.add(3,"Hello", IntentToPass);
```

And  call method which is processing given data by this way:

```
nh.addNotification(OneListItem);
```

What data structure is best to use for this (data structure will be always same) and how howt to define it?

I tried something like this but without luck:

```
List<String, Integer, Intent> li = new ArrayList<String, Integer, Intent>;
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap this and create my own class:

```
class MyClass {
    private String str;
    private Integer i1;
    private Integer i2;

    // ctrs, getters, setters
}
```

And then simply:

```
List<MyCLass> li = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually... you can do also this way, that's a lot more similar to what you asked.

WARNING: I'm not suggesting to use it, I'm only saying it's possible to do so.

```
Intent intent;

ArrayList<Object[]> objects = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
objects.add(new Object[]{1,"Hello", intent});
objects.add(new Object[]{2,"Hello", intent});
objects.add(new Object[]{3,"World", intent});

Log.d("OUTPUT", objects.get(2)[1]); // it prints out "World"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a class for whatever type of information you're trying to store. For example:

```
class Person {
    public final String name;
    public final int age;
    public final boolean gender;
    public Person(String name, int age, boolean gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

And then the list would be used like so:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(person1);
people.add(person2);
people.add(person3);
```

The use of `public final` member variables for the "container" class could also be replaced with member variables declared `public` and not `final`, allowing them to be modified. It all depends on whether or not you want the class to be immutable or not and how you want to manipulate the data.

For a simple "container" class like this, I'd argue against using getters / setters because it's really just unnecessary coding. Just use `public` non-`final` variables. However, using getters or setters may be necessary to implement synchronization or other processing when the class is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiKeyMap of apache commons or you can define your own custom class that will hold the data you require.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class:

```
public class MyNotificationItem {
    private final int first;
    private final String second;
    private final int third;

    public MyNotificationItem(int first, String second, int third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public int getThird() {
        return third;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no adequate representation for that  in the standard library. Easiest would be to create your own `Triple<A,B,C>` class and then work with a `List<Triple<String,Integer,Intent>>`.

```
public final class Triple<A,B,C>{
   public final A _1; //public final to avoid getters on example
   public final B _2;
   public final C _3;

   public Triple(A a, B b, C c){
     this._1 = a;
     this._2 = b;
     this._3 = c;
  }
}

//usage would be like this
List<Triple<String, Integer, Intent>> li = new ArrayList<>;
Triple<String, Integer, Intent> t = new Triple(1,"Hello", IntentToPass);
li.add(t);
```

Or, you can use an external library, for example [the Triple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html) from Apache commons

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyNotificationItem {
    private final int first;
    private final String second;
    private final int third;

    public MyNotificationItem(int first, String second, int third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public int getThird() {
        return third;
    }
}

class OneListItem extends ArrayList<MyNotificationItem>{
     public void add(Integer i, String j, Intent k)){
         add(new MyNotificationItem(i, j, k));
    }
}
```